# Can somebody explain me this typedef from libusb?

Tags: c, typedef

I want to convert the libusb.h into PureBasic code and now I have this line:

```
typedef void (LIBUSB_CALL *libusb_transfer_cb_fn)(struct libusb_transfer *transfer);
```

What does this typedef do?

Later on there are lines like this:

```
void LIBUSB_CALL libusb_free_device_list(libusb_device **list, int unref_devices);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

LIBUSB_CALL is just a type annotation. It probably doesn't do anything.

This declares a type "f" that is a function pointer returning void and taking "params":

```
typedef void (*f)(params...)
```

libusb_transfer_cb_fn is a type representing a function pointer tacking a pointer to a libusb_transfer struct and returning nothing (void).

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for `typedef` in C is peculiar.  What you do is write an ordinary declaration:

```
int x, *y, z[2];
```

and then insert the keyword `typedef` in front.  This tells the compiler that, for each variable declared, don't actually declare a variable; instead, make that a new name for the type that the variable would have had, if it were a variable.  So:

```
typedef int x, *y, z[2];
```

makes `x` an alias for `int`, `y` an alias for `int *`, and `z` an alias for `int [2]`.

If you take the `typedef` off the original line you get:

```
void (LIBUSB_CALL *libusb_transfer_cb_fn)(struct libusb_transfer *transfer);
```

(which is only syntactically valid if `LIBUSB_CALL` is a macro, probably some compiler-specific modifier like `__stdcall` or `__fastcall`), which is already a little peculiar because of C's need to parenthesize pointers-to-functions.  But it would declare (and define) `libusb_transfer_cb_fn` as a variable of type "pointer to function taking one argument (the transfer thing) and returning `void`.  So the `typedef` makes `libusb_transfer_cb_fn` an alias for that type.

The name obviously (well... :-) ) means: "callback function for libusb after a transfer operation".

The idea would be that a later bit of C code might read something like:

```
extern libusb_transfer_cb_fn abc_func;
```

which tells you that there's some global variable `abc_func` of type "pointer to libusb callback", or:

```
some_return_type xyz_func(libusb_transfer_cb_fn funcp, int a, char *b) {
    struct libusb_transfer x;
    ... some code that fills in x ...
    (*funcp)(&x);
}
```